# Konvas drag algorithm causes skipping as mouse passes over other page elements - broken in 1.6.2, solved in 1.6.3

Tags: javascript, konvajs

In this snippet, when I drag the green rectangle around the Konvas canvas, all is well. However when I keep dragging and the mouse moves over the top bar, for example, the green rect 'jumps' under the mouse pointer.

Am I doing something wrong?

It feels like the drag code is using a mousemove event parameter relative to the element 'under' the pointer, rather than of the page. Like maybe event.clientX & Y instead of event.pageX & Y.

EDIT: I added a grey div absolutely positioned over the canvas - try dragging the green rect across the canvas so the mouse passes over the grey box. Jumpy jumpy jumpy.

```js
// add a stage
var s = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 400,
  height: 400
});

// add a layer        
var l = new Konva.Layer();
s.add(l);

// Add a green rect to the LAYER
var green = new Konva.Rect({stroke: 'lime', width:100, height: 100, draggable: true, x: 20, y: 20});
l.add(green);

l.draw()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.2/konva.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div id="top"  style='width: 600px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #ccc;'><span>Top bar</span>
  <span> Pos: </span><span id='pos'> Drag the green rect, watch it jump when mouse moves over this bar.</span>
  </div>

  <div id="container"  style='width: 600px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #ccc;'></div>

  <div id="blob"  style='width: 40px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #ccc; position: absolute; left: 250px; top: 80px;'></div>


</body>
```

Comment: Same happens if you drag to the left. Same would happen to right and bottom as well if you could see it. Seems to happen when draggable leaves its container. Maybe you can change this behaviour with dragBoundFunc

Comment: Thanks @juvian. I was aware of that too, just wanted to keep the example simple.  It seems to me that I inadvertently drag the shape 'over' another element then it should not jump as it is doing. I am pretty sure that it was OK in an earlier version of Konvas.js before May this year.

Comment: Only similar thing I found https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/231. Maybe you should open new issue

Comment: @juvian - yes [#231](https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/231) is exactly it I believe.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat This is a bug. I am going to fix it soon. It will be very helpful if you can create another github issue with the demo that you provided in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug. It is fixed with the new release `v1.6.3`  and now it should work as expected.

Comment: Excellent thanks @lavrton. Sorry only just returned to see your request for a Github issue. Shall I still set one up or is it too late now?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat ah, no. We don't need it now. :)

Comment: I can confirm that in my repro snippet in my question, if I replace 1.6.3 in the script url then the bug is gone. Well done.Thanks.